# Problems with downloading copies of signed documents on my server through the docusign api

Tags: docusignapi

A confirmation and status pdf(certificate maybe) gets downloaded when i try to download the real pdf document that the user signed. I have a need to keep local copies of signed documents on my server.

```
 public class DownloadEnvelopeDocs
    {
        static string email = "***";            
        static string password = "*****";           
        static string integratorKey = "*************";      
        public static string envelopeId = "******"; 
        static string baseURL = "";         


    // main()

    public static void Main()
    {

        try
        {
            //============================================================================
            //  STEP 1 - Login API Call (used to retrieve your baseUrl)
            //============================================================================

            // Endpoint for Login api call (in demo environment):
            string url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";

            // set request url, method, and headers.  No body needed for login api call
            HttpWebRequest request = initializeRequest(url, "GET", null, email, password);

            // read the http response
            string response = getResponseBody(request);

            // parse baseUrl from response body
            baseURL = parseDataFromResponse(response, "baseUrl");

            //--- display results
            Console.WriteLine("\nAPI Call Result: \n\n" + prettyPrintXml(response));

            //============================================================================
            //  STEP 2 - Get Envelope Document(s) List and Info
            //============================================================================

            // append "/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents" to to baseUrl and use for next endpoint
            url = baseURL + "/envelopes/" + envelopeId + "/documents";

            // set request url, method, body, and headers
            request = initializeRequest(url, "GET", null, email, password);

            // read the http response
            response = getResponseBody(request);

            // store each document name and uri locally, so that we can subsequently download each one
            Dictionary<string, string> docsList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            string uri, name;
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(response)))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "envelopeDocument"))
                    {
                        XmlReader reader2 = reader.ReadSubtree();
                        uri = ""; name = "";
                        while (reader2.Read())
                        {
                            if ((reader2.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader2.Name == "name"))
                            {
                                name = reader2.ReadString();
                            }
                            if ((reader2.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader2.Name == "uri"))
                            {
                                uri = reader2.ReadString();
                            }
                        }// end while
                        docsList.Add(name, uri);
                    }
                }
            }

            //--- display results
            Console.WriteLine("\nAPI Call Result: \n\n" + prettyPrintXml(response));

            //============================================================================
            //  STEP 3 - Download the Document(s)
            //============================================================================

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in docsList)
            {
                // append document uri to baseUrl and use to download each document(s)
                url = baseURL + kvp.Value;
                // set request url, method, body, and headers
                request = initializeRequest(url, "GET", null, email, password);
                request.Accept = "application/pdf"; // documents are converted to PDF in the DocuSign cloud

                // read the response and store into a local file:
                HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Documents/") + envelopeId + ".pdf";
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                using (FileStream outfile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    webResponse.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(ms);
                    if (ms.Length > int.MaxValue)
                    {
                        throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot write a file larger than 2GB.");
                    }
                    outfile.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length);

                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nDone downloading document(s), check local directory.");
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            using (WebResponse response = e.Response)
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
                using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    string text = new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(prettyPrintXml(text));
                }
            }
        }
    } // end main()

    //***********************************************************************************************
    // --- HELPER FUNCTIONS ---
    //***********************************************************************************************
    public static HttpWebRequest initializeRequest(string url, string method, string body, string email, string password)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = method;
        addRequestHeaders(request, email, password);
        if (body != null)
            addRequestBody(request, body);
        return request;
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static void addRequestHeaders(HttpWebRequest request, string email, string password)
    {
        // authentication header can be in JSON or XML format.  XML used for this walkthrough:
        string authenticateStr =
            "<DocuSignCredentials>" +
                "<Username>" + email + "</Username>" +
                "<Password>" + password + "</Password>" +
                "<IntegratorKey>" + integratorKey + "</IntegratorKey>" + // global (not passed)
                "</DocuSignCredentials>";
        request.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authenticateStr);
        request.Accept = "application/xml";
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static void addRequestBody(HttpWebRequest request, string requestBody)
    {
        // create byte array out of request body and add to the request object
        byte[] body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody);
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(body, 0, requestBody.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static string getResponseBody(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        // read the response stream into a local string
        HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        return responseText;
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static string parseDataFromResponse(string response, string searchToken)
    {
        // look for "searchToken" in the response body and parse its value
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(response)))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == searchToken))
                    return reader.ReadString();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static string prettyPrintXml(string xml)
    {
        // print nicely formatted xml
        try
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            return doc.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return xml;
        }
    }
} // end class
```

Comment: So what problems are you having?  You haven't specified what's happening, are the documents corrupt?  Do you not receive them? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response to the **Get Document List** request (GET /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents) will have an **envelopeDocuments** array that contains an object for each document in the Envelope, plus an object for the "Certificate of Completion" pdf (i.e., the certificate that DocuSign produces for each and every transaction, which contains audit trail information about the transaction).  For example, the following **Get Document List** response is for an Envelope that contained 3 documents:

```
{
    "envelopeId": "37A2A639-E9EF-4FD3-A390-3E6621897CD9",
    "envelopeDocuments": [
        {
            "documentId": "1",
            "name": "Test_1.pdf",
            "type": "content",
            "uri": "/envelopes/37A2A639-E9EF-4FD3-A390-3E6621897CD9/documents/1",
            "order": "1",
            "pages": "1"
        },
        {
            "documentId": "2",
            "name": "Test_2.pdf",
            "type": "content",
            "uri": "/envelopes/37A2A639-E9EF-4FD3-A390-3E6621897CD9/documents/2",
            "order": "2",
            "pages": "1"
        },
        {
            "documentId": "3",
            "name": "Test_3.pdf",
            "type": "content",
            "uri": "/envelopes/37A2A639-E9EF-4FD3-A390-3E6621897CD9/documents/3",
            "order": "3",
            "pages": "1"
        },
        {
            "documentId": "certificate",
            "name": "Summary",
            "type": "summary",
            "uri": "/envelopes/37A2A639-E9EF-4FD3-A390-3E6621897CD9/documents/certificate",
            "order": "999",
            "pages": "4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice that the **envelopeDocuments** array contains four document objects -- one for each of the three documents in the Envelope, and one representing the "Certificate of Completion" pdf.  If your issue is just that you do not want to download the Certificate of Completion, you can simply ignore (i.e., not process/download) the document object that has **documentId = certificate**.